# Jquery : Want to disable all the input fields if editqastatus value = 1 or 2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Jquery : Want to disable all the input fields in the modal form if input field editqastatus value = 1 or 2.

function editMember(id = null) {
    if(id) {

```
    // remove the error 
    $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
    $(".text-danger").remove();
    // empty the message div
    $(".edit-messages").html("");

    // remove the id
    $("#member_id").remove();

    // fetch the member data
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php_action/getSelectedMember.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {member_id : id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(response) {

        $("#editqastatus").val(response.qastatus);
        $("#editdisqreason").val(response.disqreason);
        $("#editcampaignname").val(response.campaignname);
        $("#editassettitle").val(response.assettitle);


            // here update the member data
            $("#updateMemberForm").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
```

Comment: please give us the if condition and which inputs do you want to disable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure if you are talking about this:

```
   if ($("#editqastatus").val() == 1 || $("#editqastatus").val() == 2) {
        $(".modal").find('input').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
    } else {
        $(".modal").find('input').removeAttr('disabled')
    }
```

replace the `".modal"` with the class wrapping your inputs in the modal.

Comment: Thank you so much brother... Please suggest any site from where i can  learn AJAX and Jquery ...